# Regular expression to find specific words in a text file in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have written a console app that reads in a text file full of data.

I had to extract any telephone numbers from it and put them into a results file.

I used several RegEx's to do this to cover several different formats of telephone numbers i.e. UK, US, international etc.

Here is an example of one I used -

```
string sPattern = "^\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$";
```

This would look for telephone numbers in the following format - 123-456-7890

My question being, I now want to write a RegEx that looks for key **words** as apposed to numbers.

E.g. If I read in a data file I would want it to find key words 'White' and 'Car'.

And then put them into the results file.

Is there a method of doing this?

Comment: Look into using Regex's If conditional and named match captures. Place differing items into the named captures and on the C# side check to see if the named match capture is not null and handle appropriately. I discuss the if conditional on my blog article entitled [Regular Expressions and the If Conditional](http://omegacoder.com/?p=56). HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex.Matches():

```
string pattern = "car";
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None);
MatchCollection mc = rx.Matches(inputText);

foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: Good input only thing is when I try to implement it it says that RegexOptions is a type being used as a variable therefore does not run.

Comment: Yes, that's invalid.  @Antoine, did you mean `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`?

Comment: RegexOptions was just a placeholder to indicate you can specify some options. It's not mandatory so you can just specify the pattern. But if you need them, look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx.

Comment: `pattern` should be: `@"\b(?:White|Car)\b"`

Answer (score 2):

Just use the word, delimited by word boundaries;

```
string sPattern = @"\bKeyword\b";
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 1):

The method you're looking for is:

`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(string input. string pattern)`

This medhod indicates if the regular expression finds a match in the input string. It returns `true` if there is a match, `false` otherwise.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=VS.100%29.aspx first example has what you need.